# How to get separate row for joined data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have entities that have names in table `name` with key `name_id`. These names can have "alternative forms", in the same table, with foreign key `primary_name_id`. The thing is, only primary names are referenced for entities. So if I want both primary and alternative names for some entities, I can do:

```
SELECT e.entity_id, n.name_id
FROM entity e
JOIN entity_to_name e2n ON e2n.entity_id = e.entity_id
JOIN name n ON e2n.name_id = n.name_id

UNION

SELECT e.entity_id, na.name_id
FROM entity e
JOIN entity_to_name e2n ON e2n.entity_id = e.entity_id
JOIN name n ON e2n.name_id = n.name_id
JOIN name na ON na.primary_name_id = n.name_id
```

EDIT: Example of tables and desired result:

```
-------------------
entity_id | name_id
-------------------
entity1   | n1
entity2   | n2
entity3   | n3
-------------------

-----------------------------------
name_id   | primary_name_id  | name
-----------------------------------
n1        | NULL             | Entity 1
n2        | NULL             | Entity 2
n3        | NULL             | Entity 3
n4        | n1               | Entity Uno
n5        | n2               | Entity Duo
n6        | n2               | Entity Zwei
------------------------------------

And as a result I want

---------------------
entity_id  |  name_id
---------------------
entity1    | n1
entity1    | n4
entity2    | n2
entity2    | n5
entity2    | n6
entity3    | n3
```

But in reality, JOIN-path to names is more complicated, and I would like to avoid doing it twice. Is there any way to do this in one query?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below should give you the expected answer:

```
SELECT  n.name_id
, e.entity_Id
FROM name n
LEFT JOIN entity e 
   ON coalesce(n.primary_name_id, n.name_id) = e.name_id
```

Comment: JOIN on COALESCE is interesting, but I assume you there should be no COALESCE in SELECT clause - otherwise there would be only primary names in result, right?